# How i can map any object value string to boolean?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I try to do it, but i have error
Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'NextType'.
How i can avoid this?

```
type A = {
  a: string
}

type B = {
  a: boolean
};

type NextType<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[keyof T] extends string ? boolean : string
}

const a: A = {
  a: 'a',
}

function mapObjectStringPropToBoolean<T extends object>(
  key: keyof T,
  payload: T
): NextType<T> {
  const value = payload[key];
  return {
    [key]: Boolean(value)
  } // as NextType<T> works!
}

let result: B = mapObjectStringPropToBoolean('a', a);
```

Comment: Take `const b: B = {a: true}`, then `NextType<B>` is `{a: string;}`. `mapObjectStringPropToBoolean('a', b);` is clearly trying to return a wrong type - TS compiler is right in flagging it as error.

Comment: @Lesiak - That was my first thought too, but even when I lock it down, I still get the error the OP gets: https://tsplay.dev/w6v76w I feel like I'm being a bit slow this morning. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `NextType` in your code maps all properties to boolean - but the code returns an object with only one property.

Comment: No matter how we spin it, the type assertion will always be needed. When we construct an object having `key` which is `keyof T` as a property, TypeScript will always give the type of this object an index signature. This would only work if `key` would be a union of number/string literals already known at compile time.

Comment: @Lesiak - Not really my code, I was just trying to close the loophole we'd both noticed in the **OP**'s code.

Comment: @Lesiak Yes, I forgot to return the rest object, thanks it helped. Can you write an answer so I can choose it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an overload to get TypeScript off your back about the return type?

```
function mapObjectStringPropToBoolean<T extends object>(
  key: keyof T,
  payload: T
): NextType<T>; // moved to external signature
function mapObjectStringPropToBoolean<T>(key: keyof T, payload: T) {
  const value = payload[key];

  return {
    [key]: Boolean(value)
  }
}
```

Seems to work, and in tooltips, the overload signature will be shown, not the function declaration's.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY39EN)

Comment: Seems like a hidden type assertion. :-| If there has to be one, it may as well be explicit. Inventive, though. ;-)